# C++ Beep not working

Tags: c++, beep, piano

I am a novice programmer and I am trying to make a piano with C++, using the Beep function. the problem is, I can't hear the sounds when I press the keys. Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool ciclo = true;
    char tecla = _getch();
    while (ciclo);
    if (tecla == 'd'){
        Beep(261, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'f'){
        Beep(293, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'g'){
        Beep(329, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'h'){
        Beep(349, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'j'){
        Beep(392, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'k'){
        Beep(440, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'l'){
        Beep(493, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'k'){
        Beep(523, 100);
    }

    if (tecla == 'q'){
        ciclo = false;
    };
    if (tecla == 'r'){
        Beep(277, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 't'){
        Beep(312, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'u'){
        Beep(370, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'i'){
    Beep(415, 100);
    }
    if (tecla == 'o'){
        Beep(466, 100);
    }

}
```

I seriously can't find anything wrong in it, so any help would be appreciated. I'm compiling on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: which compiler you using ?

Comment: `while (ciclo);` is an infinite loop. The program never gets past this line.

Comment: Thank you, Igor, I see my problem, thank you. I ran another program once that used the beep function and it worked, that's why I found it strange that it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your computer has not PC speaker. Look at the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA, I was just about to say... modern computers don't really come with them...  I saw this question and was thinking about all of the times I did a PC build that didn't work and I had no idea what was wrong :)

Comment: actually, my PC does have a speaker, I used the beep function once and it worked. That's why I asked

Answer (score 5):

While it is true that your computer may not have those inbuilt speakers. Your code is also stuck in a infinite loop.

```
while (ciclo);
```

I suggest you loop as long as the key is not q so that the user then may quit.

Here is a example of your code working.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    while (char tecla = _getch() != 'q')
    {
        if (tecla == 'd'){
            Beep(261, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'f'){
            Beep(293, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'g'){
            Beep(329, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'h'){
            Beep(349, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'j'){
            Beep(392, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'k'){
            Beep(440, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'l'){
            Beep(493, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'k'){
            Beep(523, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'r'){
            Beep(277, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 't'){
            Beep(312, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'u'){
            Beep(370, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'i'){
        Beep(415, 100);
        }
        if (tecla == 'o'){
            Beep(466, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most modern PCs don't come with an inbuilt speaker.

By your include statements, I can see that you're using Windows. Windows usually uses the system's default message sound (the "ding" you hear when a dialog box appears). Make sure you have your speakers turned on, or maybe try another solution that doesn't use Beep.